# in c , when i assign a string in conditional statement it has error

Tags: c, scope, char, declaration, c-strings

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a = 1;
    if (a == 1) {
        char name[] = "hello";
    }

    printf("%s", name);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried some methods like char name[] = "hello"  and it has no error.
but why above statement has error?
i don't know why this error happen.
i think the compiler first check the printf("%s", name); and second order as conditional statement?
then how i can assign string into name (not use pointer)?

Comment: The **scope** of `char name[]` is limited to the code block where it is defined. Outside that, it is not visible / does not exist. Start with say `char name[100] = "";` and then assign another value to it if needed with `strncpy()` or `snprintf()`.

Comment: oh, thank you for your kindness. the c language is very complicate!!!

Comment: Another way, if you don't want to manipulate the string much, would be to define a *pointer* such as `char *name = "";` and then reassign it with `name = "hello";` This isn't copying any string; it just reassigns the *pointer* to another fixed string.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the variable `name` is the sub-statement (the block of the compound statement) of the if statement

```
if (a == 1) {
    char name[] = "hello";
}
```

outside the if sub-statement the name `name` is not visible.

From the C Standard (6.8.4 Selection statements)

> 3 A selection statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of
> the scope of its enclosing block. **Each associated substatement is
> also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the
> selection statement.**

You could define the variable name before the if statement as for example

```
char *name = "";

if (a == 1) {
    name = "hello";
}
```

Or instead of the pointer you could declare an array as for example

```
char name[6];
name[0] = '\0';

if (a == 1) {
    strcpy( name, "hello" );
}
```